# Node.js require() does not look in parent directory when using "npm link"

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm developing a module for node.js. For development I'm using "npm link" which basically creates a sym link on the drive (I'm running Ubuntu) to the development location of this module.

When I use require to load a module that the parent application has in it's node_modules folder it is not getting loaded. I instead get a "cannot find module x". I set the environment variable NODE_DEBUG to module and found that it is looking "up" only from the physical location on the drive, not from inside the project.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how I fix this? My current solution is to now unfortunately physically copy the module code into my test project as part of the startup script which is not cool!

Personally I think this might be a bug, but I wasn't sure if it was behaving as expected and I was just doing it wrong.

[image]

Comment: Could you draw your directory structure? I'd like to see which script contains the broken require, where it is in your dir structure, and what you expect to be resolved in that require. It's difficult to follow what you're trying to do. I don't understand what you parent application is or what you are trying to require from where, so drawing the dir structure will be really helpful.

Comment: I've added an image to my post. The first folder the NPM linked module checks is My Projects/Module Project, then My Projects/. It never checks anything inside My Porjects/Node Project/, even though that is where the link is and that is contextually where the module exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand how you think that it's "contextually where the module exists", but unfortunately `npm link <module>` just creates a normal symlink under `node_modules`. From the context of the linked module, it is not aware (and couldn't reasonably know) that it is symlinked to from other directories.

The require behaviour is complex, but essentially it looks up through the parent directories for node_modules directories, which is correct behaviour. The problem you have is the general problem of peer dependencies, which there are a few solutions for. Rather than linking to `Module Project`, you could put all of your projects inside a `node_modules` directory

[image: peer dependencies]

`Node Project` can just require from `Module Project`, and likewise, `Module Project` can require from `Node Project`. If they both require from each other then there could be big problems with circular dependencies, so watch out for that.

It might be helpful if you explain exactly what the linked `Module Project` is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

That is what module [parent-require](https://www.npmjs.org/package/parent-require) tries to solve. Though it would have been better if the core require handled this by its own.

Answer (score 2):

It's a while since your post, but maybe you or others are still interested in a solution for that problem, that I was also facing for a long time.

Just as a side remark, in node v 6.x the correct behavior was actually implemented but because of sideeffects it is currently behind a flag [--preserve-symlinks](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/cli.html#cli_preserve_symlinks). So even aplying this flag might cause those side effects, why it was removed from default behavior.

Until that is fixed from node.js side, you still can use the following workarround:

set `NODE_PATH` to `./node_modules`

Doing that e.g., with browserify in a build script:

```
"scripts": {
  "build:debug": "NODE_PATH=./node_modules browserify src/index.js > dist/build.js"
}
```

where ./node_modules is the node_modules folder in your root application directory causes node to search in that folder if the module is not found elsewhere.

For **Windows** users I recomment to install the cross-env module to set the environment variable correctly. The build script then would look like:

```
"scripts": {
  "build:debug": "cross-env NODE_PATH=./node_modules browserify src/index.js > dist/build.js"
}
```

This workarround finally solved the problems I had before with peer-dependencies not found in linked modu